# Calling a static library function from another dynamic link library project

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I have a static library and it has a class like below in its header file:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        void Something();
    };
}
```

I linked above static library with my another dynamic link library project, and now I can call above function like below:

```
int Main()
{
    MyNameSpace::MyClass A;
    A.Something();
}
```

Although above works fine, I like to use my static library function like below, instead declaring classes:

```
int Main()
{
    MyNameSpace::Something();
}
```

But I am wondering about the correct way to do this.

I tried it in static library like:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    void Something();
}
```

and after linking static library to the dynamic library, tried to use the function in it like:

```
MyNameSpace::Something();
```

But, IntelliSense doesn't see it and I already included my static library's header file and linked it properly.

*What I want to do is declare a function in a static library outside classes and make it visible to another projects whose it linked into. In this case, to dynamic library.*

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say you "linked" the static library, do you mean you linked it to the dynamic library, or the final executable?

Comment: no, linked to the dynamic library. Final executable don't use this function. This function only used in dynamic library. I had to make a separate static library because I had to handle SEH excetions in it. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do what I want by declaring the function like below:

*In Static Library:*

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    void Something();
}
```

*In Dynamic Link Library:*

```
MeNameSpace::Something();
```

Now the function is visible even outside file scope.